# Python, understanding list-comprehension

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension

I'm learning data structures and I wanted to put the data in the stack into a list and I did it using this code

```
data_list=[Stack1.pop() for data in range(Stack1.get_top()+1)]
```

Now this does achieve it. But I would like know

- even though the variable 'data' is not being used in the expression 'Stack1.pop()' , the comprehension works. Please explain it's working with an example, where the variable is not being used in the expression.
- whether this approach is good w.r.to stack, queue ?

Comment: re: "whether this approach is good" – if `get_top()` has its conventional meaning, then no. You'll need to describe `Stack1` in more detail for anyone to be able to answer properly, though. What type is it, what methods does that type support and what do they do, what's the content, etc.

Comment: get_top() method is conventional, and Stack1 has integers in it as data

Comment: In that case, the listcomp will only work by coincidence if the value on top of the stack happens to be the size of the stack - 1.

Comment: To answer your question, although this list comprehension will only work sometimes and only by chance, it's fine to have a variable in a listcomp that you don't use. By convention, this variable is usually called `_` to indicate that it isn't actually used.

Comment: Oh, thanks for pointing that, it answered my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like any list comprehension, you can modify your code into an equivalent `for` loop with repeated `append` calls:

```
data_list = []
for _ in range(Stack1.get_top()+1):
    data_list.append(Stack1.pop())
```

The code works (I assume) because `get_top` returns one less than the size of the stack. It does have a side effect though, of emptying out the stack, which may or may not be what you want.

A more natural way of using the items from a stack is to use a `while` loop:

```
while not some_stack.is_empty():
    item = stack.pop()
    do_something(item)
```

The advantage of the `while` loop is that it will still work if `do_something` modifies the stack (either by pushing new values or popping off additional ones).

A final note: It's not usually necessary to use a special stack type in Python. Lists have `O(1)` methods to `append()` and `pop()` from the end of the list. If you want the items from a list in the order they'd be `pop`ped, you can just reverse it using the `list.reverse()` method (to reverse in place), the `reversed` builtin function (to get a reverse iterator), or an "alien smiley" slice (`some_list[::-1]`; to get a reversed copy of the list).

Comment: I understood 'while' loop approach but I wanted to know.                             list1=[<expr> for <variable> in <list>]
      in this comprehension if the <variable> is not being used in the <expr>  is it fine?   If yes, provide an example. Thank you

Comment: It's *allowed* to not use the variable in the expression. Whether it's a good idea or not is a bit more ambiguous. You'll see it pretty often with a `range`s and variable named `_` (to indicate that you don't care about its value).